# Use NSTimer of UILocalNotification for timer app when phone goes to sleep?

Tags: ios, nstimer, uilocalnotification

I know the question I'm asking has been asked before, but I cannot find an complete answer to it.

My question is this: I want to create small timer application that counts down from 20 minutes (user preference) to 0. The user can see how much time is remaining. When the timer has run out, it should play a sound file three times. 
I have created an app that does just that by using NSTimer. The only problem is that after a few minutes, the iPhone enters sleeps mode and the app stalls. When I wake up the phone the countdown has stopped at the time the phone went to sleep.

I understand that a few solutions exist for this problem.

1. Use a soundless audio file and fraudulently act as if the app requires a background audio resource (with the risk of app rejection by Apple)
2. Use `UILocalNotification` which is supposed to be able to run in the background. But from what I understand, this method can only play a sound file once, so that would be insufficient.

But apart from that, should I:

1. Use `UILocalNotification` instead of `NSTimer` (so quit `NSTimer` altogether) in my app?
2. Use `UILocalNotification` from the moment the phone enters sleep mode (and then switch back to `NSTimer` in case the user wakes up the phone)?

Answer (score 3):

Go with your second option. Use an `NSTimer` while the app is open. When the app is going to be background, invalidate any timers and install instances of `UILocalNotification` with appropriate fire dates.

When the app comes back, read the pending local notifications, start timers for the associated fire dates and cancel the local notifications.

Create a sound file that includes your 'single sound' being played 3 times.

p.s. `UILocalNotification` doesn't run in the background. Local notifications are registered with iOS as events and when the fire date comes around iOS takes an associated action.

Comment: This is the correct answer. A couple of things to bear in mind is the obvious one that the user can disable notifications, but the less obvious is that if the user turns off the device or reboots it when the local notification is due to fire then it won't fire "retrospectively". This may or may not be important to you, just informing you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers, will try it and let you know the outcome